# Vimeo captions not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, vimeo, cc, captions, closed-captions

I have VTT closed captions files that I generated from YouTube.  After some edits, I uploaded the .vtt file into my Vimeo version of the video.

I see the captions on Chrome but not in IE.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this solution.  Just delete the extra lines at the top.

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions  (delete this line)
Language: en    (delete this line also)

00:00:00.890 --> 00:00:04.770
```